# Is $2\mathrm p_z$ orbital wave function three- or four-dimensional?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, dimension-theory-analysis

The wave function of the $2\mathrm{p}_z$ orbital is

$$Ψ = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2π}}\left(\frac Z a\right)^{5/2} r \mathrm e^{-Zr/a}\cos θ.$$

I'm confused if this function will be a three-dimensional function or a four-dimensional function?

My professor told me that

$$z/r = \cos θ,$$

where $θ$ is the angle made by $r$ with the $z$ axis. So, I guess it will be four-dimensional since we would have to then plug in

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$

in the equation.

But when he plotted the function, he plotted a three-dimensional one! What is the correct answer and why?

Comment: hello have you heard of physics or chemistry stack exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrogen-like orbitals are always 3-dimensional. But, since we can't directly visualize functions $\mathbb R^3\mapsto \mathbb R$, to plot them you need some trick.

One of such tricks it to take a cross section of the 3D space, e.g. xOz plane, and plot the function inside this plane. Then, knowing that the function is symmetric with respect to rotation around the $z$ axis, you can imagine what it could look like in other cross sections (or just plot these too). Here's an example:

[image: xOz plot of the orbital from the OP]

Another way is to draw the function in a *density plot*. This will look like a cloud of colored points, with their opacity depending on the function value. Example (here blue is negative, orange is positive):

[image: density plot of the same orbital]

Comment: So while plotting wave functions, the first axis is x,the second is y and the third is $Ψ$ instead of z, right?

Comment: @DylanRodrigues that all depends on what cross section you choose. One of the axes should indeed be $\Psi$, but the others are allocated by the one who is plotting.

Comment: I have a similar doubt in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4001487/doubt-in-graph-of-wave-function Please answer this too if possible