# Doubt in graph of wave function

Tags: graphing-functions

The 1s orbital in polar coordinates is given by:
$Ψ=2(1/a_0)^2*e^{-r/a_0}$
I am confused if $r^2$ here is $x^2+y^2$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2$(here z is nothing but  $Ψ$ itself) .When my professor graphed this function,it looked like a sheet with a hump in the middle.If i substitute  $r^2$=$x^2+y^2$ and plot the function, it matches the prfoessor's graph.Substituting the other option gives the wrong answer.But I learnt in the theory of spherical polar coordinates that $r^2$=$x^2+y^2+z^2$.
Basically,I want to convert the polar system to a cartesian system.Where am I going wrong?
[image]

Comment: This is basically the same question as [the previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4000733/64206). Your professor just chose to plot the xOy cross section of $\Psi$. In this plane $z=0$, but it still exists. In fact, it might just as easily be $xOz$ or $yOz$, since the function is spherically symmetric.

Comment: The professor didn't plot the cross section;He plotted the entire 3d function on a 3d graph plotter

Comment: A plot of the entire function would be a 4D hypersurface. He's surely plotted a cross section, and either didn't declare it (thinking it's obvious), or you've missed it. In any case, (especially if you still don't believe me) just ask the professor.

Comment: i've added the picuture to the answer

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't contradict what I said. In any cross section that goes through $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ this function will look the same due to its symmetry.